# Magento 2 - How can I remove the white borders from images in product list page?

Tags: magento2

Magento 2 -  How can I remove the white borders from images in product list page?

how can i remove white frame around image in product list page

Answer (score 4):

You have to add false to view.xml in YOUR_THEME/etc/view.xml to the "category_page_list" image ID.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <media>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">
            <image id="category_page_list" type="small_image">
                <width>240</width>
                <height>300</height>
                <transparency>false</transparency>
            </image>
        </images>
    </media>
</view>
```

Comment: I try but this is not working still get border frame  top and bottom side of the product image

Comment: the sollution I posted is to remove from the resize function but if your image is smaller than the resize width and height it will have that border you can check this link to see all the options for resize and image parameters http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-images.html

Comment: i have set height and width issue has been resolve<image id="category_page_grid" type="small_image">
                <width>250</width>
                <height>250</height>
            </image>thanks

Comment: Good to hear that, you coul also mark the question as resolved so others know and use the fix

Comment: @VladPatru, after this also i can see white background left and right

Comment: @jafarpinjar you need to remove your images cache folder from `pub/media/catalog/product/cache` I just checked and that should solve

Answer (score 2):

in view.xml set "width" and "height" as you wish and then "aspect_ratio" and "frame" to "false"

[image]