# Remove white background from thumbnail images in Magento 2.1.3

Tags: magento2

I want to remove white background from thumbnail images in my custom theme.

I have created custom theme for **Magento 2.1.3**
I made changes in order summary layout but when I try to load images on checkout page, it comes with white background at top and bottom.

I tried almost all solution available on stack overflow but no luck.
Any help would me appreciate.

[image]

Comment: Not sure about Magento2 but in magento1 we used to add keepFrame(false) before resizing an image. You can try that also.

Comment: I guess you can set a custom height and width to the image..So you can extend the images till the edge of the white background covering entire white space..

Comment: Try this on your image object `->setKeepFrame(false)`. You can find this on this class `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image`

Comment: @Kartik, this won't work. i did try.

Answer (score 4):

In `<vendor>/<theme>/etc/view.xml` you should be able to adjust the settings of the image to remove the frame, like this:

```
<image id="category_page_grid" type="small_image">
    <width>610</width>
    <height>360</height>
    <frame>false</frame>
</image>
```

***However***, there is an issue where setting `<frame>` to false returns true. [See this Github issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4622), it was recently merged into the `develop` branch. If you're not using the `develop` branch for your site you'll still need to use the below fix until it's offically released:

> After creating a plugin to convert the string value to an integer (which
>   properly casts to a boolean), the image frame is not added.
>
> ```
> public function beforeSetKeepFrame($image, $keep)
> {
>     if (is_string($keep)) {
>         $keep = (strtolower($keep) === 'true') ? 1 : 0;
>     }
>     return [$keep];
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add false to view.xml in YOUY_THEME/etc/view.xml to the "category_page_list"

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <media>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">
            <image id="category_page_list" type="small_image">
                <width>240</width>
                <height>300</height>
                <transparency>false</transparency>
            </image>
        </images>
    </media>
</view>
```

You can also check here
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/148911/43587