# Magento 2.3 Product detail page main image with white background

Tags: magento2.3, product-images

I have inserted the image into the product and check then product coming with the white background.How to remove this white background and display image small ?

[image]

Comment: Can't you achieve this with css? like extend the product page style in your custom theme?

Comment: This is a image not a content

Comment: tried [this Answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/169605/remove-white-background-from-thumbnail-images-in-magento-2-1-3) ?

Comment: Hello @Piyush, This is for a category page. Not for a product detail page

Comment: try the same with different image id, check that view.xml you will find all image ids related to product detail or category page

Comment: Not working bro, I have checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible solution, In `etc/view.xml` of your current theme, you can update product image size

Make sure you resize with the expect ratio.

Use additional tag `<frame>` to prevent white borders on image. Use this code as example:

```
<image id="product_page_main_image" type="small_image">
  <width>460</width>
  <height>460</height>
  <aspect_ratio>true</aspect_ratio>
  <frame>false</frame>
</image>
```

**After changes run:**

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Hello,

After changes it is required to run php bin/magento catalog:images:resize command ?

Comment: Yes, also run these commands as well  `php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`
`php bin/magento cache:clean`
`php bin/magento cache:flush`

Comment: @MuhammadHasham, I have edited please remove comments dear. and your solution seems worked

Comment: It is worked !!!